# Why isn't document.cookie getting set?

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, session-cookies

I have this JavaScript code that sets the **document.cookie** but when running it I can see **document.cookie** doesn't actually get set. See the screenshot below.

```
 (function() { 
      var offset = (new Date()).getTimezoneOffset()
      console.log("WAR");
      var date = new Date();console.log(offset);
      date.setTime(date.getTime()+3600000);
      var variable = "utc_offset="+offset+"; expires="+date.toGMTString();+"; path=/";
      console.log(variable); 
      document.cookie=variable;
})()
```

[image]

Comment: It could be because you're trying that on the new tab page, which is (probably) set up to ignore most JavaScript and cookies.

Comment: @david Opps never experience that thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because you're not on an actual webpage but on a new Chrome tab.